# Unexpected Syntax Error using '<' and '>'

Tags: python

I have been set a simple task:

Write a program for a game where the computer generates a
random starting number between 20 and 30.
The player and the computer can remove 1,2 or 3 from the number
in turns. Something like this...
Starting number : 25
How many do you want to remove? 3
22 left
Computer removes 2
20 left
The player who has to remove the last value to bring the number
down to 0 is the loser.
1 left
Computer removes 1
You win!

I am trying to create it so that the player can only enter numbers 1, 2 or 3 to remove.

I get the syntax error of invalid syntax where the if statement is:

```
import random
import time

start=random.randint(20,30)

print('Starting number is',start)

personremove=int(input('How many do you want to remove? '))

if personremove=<3 or >1:
    print('Enter a number between 1 and 3')
    personremove=int(input('How many do you want to remove? '))


current=start-personremove

print(current,'left')

compremove=random.randint(1,3)

current=start-personremove-compremove

print('Computer removes',compremove)

print(current,'left')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am only a beginner to python as you can probably tell.

Comment: what do you think this is supposed to do? `if personremove=<3 or >1:` this isn't valid Python.

Answer (score 6):

`if personremove=<3 or >1:` should be

```
if personremove <= 3 or personremove > 1:
```

Comment: The logic is incorrect. The statement should only be True if the number is *outside* the range of 1 - 3..

Comment: I'm with @MartijnPieters here ... I'm pretty sure this test will be true for *any number*.  Although, with OP's original statement, it's a little ambiguous to try to parse out what was originally meant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-order those statements:

```
if 1 < personremove <= 3:
```

python's `or` operator requires an object or expression on both the left and the right.  As you've written it, you have another *operator* on the right which is illegal.  also, `=<` isn't a python operator.  It is `<=`.

Comment: This will be true for `personremove` equal to 2 or 3, which is not what the OP wanted, I think. He wants it to be true when the value is *outside* the values 1, 2 or 3..

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I honestly don't know.  I suppose if I can't parse it, it makes it pretty easy to argue why python's interpreter can't parse it either :)

Answer (score 2):

`personremove=<3 or >1`  is not a legal expression. Use:

```
if not (1 <= personremove <= 3):
```

This makes use of [chained comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in); it roughly means the same as:

```
if personremove < 1 or personremove > 3:
```

but `personremove` is evaluated only once, and we made it clearer that the number is outside the range 1 - 3.

You probably wanted to use a `while` loop instead, to keep asking for a correct number:

```
personremove = 0
while not (1 <= personremove <= 3):
    print('Enter a number between 1 and 3')
    try:
        personremove = int(input('How many do you want to remove? '))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: `Martijn.personmove(where=BED)`

Answer (score 0):

your `if` statement only needs sligthly tweaking. Try:

```
if 1 <= personremove <= 3:
    ...
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors:

1. Your instructions are inconsistent. The only whole integer that is *Between* 1 and 3 is 2. But surely that is not what you meant. You meant Enter either 1, 2 or 3.
2. You have the syntax of the greater than backward. It should be `personremove > 3` read personremove is greater than 3.
3. You cannot just add on `>1` after the `or`, you must again state what variable should be related to `1`. This will work `personremove < 1`

   if personremove < 1 or personremove > 3:

There are also better ways to code this in general. Putting this section into a loop, for example.